# laravel not creating migrations table

Tags: php, laravel

I pulled a laravel project, but when I run

```
php artisan migrate
```

I get this error

Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'job-board.migrations' doesn't exist (SQL: select migration from migrations order by batch asc, migration asc)

my env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=job-board
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I'm running XAMPP on ubuntu, and I was able to migrate a new separate app.

Also I changed port number of mysql in XAMPP to 3307 as 3306 is already occupied.

Comment: Put "job-board" in double quotes. It is also good practice to have words separated by undescore.

Comment: same error ....

Comment: You can confirm there is `job-board.migrations` table in running server?

Comment: no its not there, even though when I run php artisan config:clear it says Migration table created successfully.

Comment: If not there, create it in db.

Comment: I've tried creating it but as soon as I get out and re-enter there are no tables in the database

Comment: Try restarting mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel keeps track of your migration's status in a database table `migrations` itself, which you need to create first. Run

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

to create that table in your set database

Comment: says Migration table created successfully.
but when I run php artisan migrate again, gives me the same error

Comment: also no migrations table found in the database

Comment: Run `php artisan config:clear` and re-do the steps. There seem to be running two MySQL servers (since port 3306 was already occupied, make sure Laravel uses the correct one, there needs to run only one MySQL server on your machine)

Comment: I was able to migrate another project using the same port which is 3307 .. I have XAMPP and I installed mysql-server because laravel wasn't connecting to XAMPP

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me

```
 php artisan migrate:install
 php artisan schema:dump
 php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).